# How can I suppress the default config location of Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

How can I have Spring Boot only look for config files under the the directories specified by  spring.config.location property and *not* look under the default location as specified in the ConfigFileApplicationListener javadoc.

Setting spring.config.location, causes the ConfigFileApplicationListener to look in both spring.config.location directories and the default locations.

Comment: Have you tried to set also the [spring.config.name](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)?
With a jvm parameter like this `-Dspring.config.name="file:/path/to/config/application.properties"`.

Comment: spring.config.name cant have a path. It is a comma separated list of filenames without the extension.  Eg. spring.config.name=myapp,common

Answer (score 0):

you can use profiles.

in your application.properties you will only have :

```
spring.profiles.active=other
```

and have a file in the same folder named application-other.properties where you define your properties.

the default properties can be in a file named application-default.properties and when you want to use it, juste change the value in application.properties to 'default'.

[Spring-boot documentation of Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)